# mod_rewrite .htaccess rewrite match with or without file extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using a php script to match request links to a site. I'm currently matching on `'jcole/'` and `'jcole'`. However I'd like to be able to match on `"jcole"`(`.php|.html|.htm`), "`jcole`/", and "`jcole`".  I'd like the match to be agnostic of whatever the file extension maybe and also not care if there are periods in the name.(for example I'd like to be able to match on "`j.cole`")

Currently I have my `.htaccess` configured like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ /loadlink.php=link=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /loadlink.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are **way** better off doing all of this from within php. Regex is not going to be able to do everything you want, especially having to deal with arbitrary periods in the name. So you'd just want the *second* rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /loadlink.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that rewrite conditions *only apply to the immediately following `RewriteRule`*.

This will send everything to the "link" parameters, only removing an arbitrary trailing slash if it exists. It's up to the `loadlink.php` script to get rid of the `.php` or random periods in the name.